# Tensorflow tf.trainable_variables(scope="") function

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I tried to simplify my tensorflow code with the following replacement:

```
f_vars = tf.trainable_variables("foo")
```

instead of the prior syntax:

```
t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
f_vars = [var for var in t_vars if var.name.startswith('foo')]
```

Before, i tried to update tensorflow to the newest version with :

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

in jupyter notebook.

Checking the version, it returned

```
TensorFlow Version: 1.8.0
```

When i tried to run it, tensorflow returned the following error.

```
TypeError: trainable_variables() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

What's wrong here? In the tensorflow documentation, you can insert an argument for scope for the tf.trainable_variables() command. --> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables

Answer (score 1):

The function call `tf.trainable_scope('foo')` requires the definition of a variable scope named 'foo'.

For Example:

```
a = tf.Variable(1, name='a')
with tf.variable_scope('foo'):
  b = tf.Variable(1, name='b')
```

To get the trainable variables you call:

```
tf.trainable_variables()
# return variables named 'a' and 'foo/b'
```

and

```
tf.trainable_variables('foo')
# returns variables named 'foo/b'
```